# Kernel of linear operator with functions having Fourier transform supported in $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

A bounded linear operator $ T: L^2 \to L^2$ with this properties :
1. Commutes with translation
2. Commutes with dilation
3. Has in its kernel functions $ f $ such that support $\hat {f} \subseteq [0,\infty) $

I already can prove that $T= f* \mu$ where $\mu $ is a tempered distribution.

Then $\int_{-\infty}^0\hat {f}(s)e^{2i\pi s x} ds =c Tf (x)$ where $ c $ is s constant. How to prove this ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Take the fourier transform of $Tf=f*\mu$

$\hat{Tf}=m(s)\hat{f}$ where $m(s)$ is the fourier transform of $\mu$

So $m(s)$ must be zero on the positive real line and non zero on the negative real line. Combining this with the dilation property implies the result you asked.